# Edit expression of an occluded textbox

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have two textboxes on exactly the same location.  I want to edit the expression on the textbox behind the front one *without* bringing the textbox to front.  Right-click -> expression always picks the front textbox.

I can select the textbox fine using either document outline or report properties but I cannot figure out how to trigger the expression editor without rightclicking. Expression is also missing from the properties section which apparently is new "feature" in SSRS 2008 R2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the textbox via the `Properties` window. At the top, you can click `Property Pages` which opens a dialogue box for entering properties. You can activate the expression editor there from beside the `Value` property.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your only option in that scenario is to directly edit the report code. As you have noted, the only way to launch the expression editor for a textbox is to right-click on it.

Taking a step back though, why do you need two textboxes overlaying one another? Could you replace this with a single textbox and use expression logic to alter the value and formatting instead?

Comment: Thanks.  Reason for 2 textboxes is that I have multiple datatypes and formatting/size attributes.  Most it sort of can be done using expression logic but it was getting really ugly.

Comment: One trick I've used before in that situation is to add columns into my dataset that return the relevant format and size codes, then use a simple expression the set the property in the report. Obviously depends on the complexity and size of your dataset as to whether this would work for you.